# Android Navigation Drawer with login activity

Tags: android

I download an android app that just only has Navigation Drawer. When start the app, it will show the navigation drawer. From the source code, i add login activity (java and layout) and set as first start activity. When click Login button, I want it navigate to the Navigation Drawer,but it has error. If i just run the Navigation Drawer activity then is work.

```
 protected void Login(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NavigationDrawer.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

---

### **Error Log**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
```

My idea is when user login, then only show the Navigation Drawer. Thank you.

Comment: show full error log

Comment: have you define activity in manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must use the Activity class that contain the NavigationDrawer

```
protected void Login(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

because it has an error on the code above, use this one:

```
protected void Login(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(NameOfThisClass.this, NavigationDrawer.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```